# JQuery Rebinding Events

Tags: jquery

If I use JQuery to set a div tag as in:

```
$('#maindiv').html(some content...);
```

then if I bind events to objects that "maindiv" now has, if I reset the html to "maindiv" at a later time, will those events still be hanging around if I choose not to re bind those events? I mean if I bind those events again after resetting the html, will I be doing double work?

Hopefully that made sense. Thanks much for any insight.

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the element content will remove all events of the inner elements.

However, you can use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events once only (so-called *delegated-events approach*):

```
$("#maindiv").on("click", "#element", function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I was thinking I read somewhere that this is the case but couldn't find that resource. Thanks much for the quick reply.

Comment: @DavidWhitten Yep, that approach is really helpful. You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you generate some html with the html function and you only use bind, any future elements that are added after the bind will not trigger any events.

The simplest way to sort this is use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) rather than bind if you're planning to add elements after the initial content has had events applied.